# VBA Macro to remove duplicates along with their neighbour cell basing on neighbour value

Tags: excel, vba

I've been trying to write a macro to delete duplicate cells/rows basing on their neighbour value too.
What I mean is that I need only the cell with the lowest value neighbour to stay, f.e.

1|1

2|1

1|2

1|0

then

2|1

1|0

I am aware of Range.RemoveDuplicates function, however I cannot use it here the right way.
My code is a bit straight approach and it doesn't always delete all the duplicates. I'm new to VBA so maybe it's because I cannot really understand where's the output from.
My code:

```
Sub usunDuplikaty3()

Dim findRange As Range, foundCell As Range, cell As Range, del As Boolean
    Set findRange = Range("A1", Range(Range("A1").End(xlDown).Address))
    For Each cell In findRange
        Set foundCell = findRange.Find(cell.Value)
        Do While Not foundCell Is Nothing And foundCell.Address <> cell.Address
            If foundCell.Offset(0, 1).Value <= cell.Offset(0, 1).Value Then
                Rows(cell.Row).Delete (xlShiftUp)
                Set cell = foundCell
                Set findRange = Range("A1", Range(Range("A1").End(xlDown).Address))
            Else
                Rows(foundCell.Row).Delete (xlShiftUp)
                Set findRange = Range("A1", Range(Range("A1").End(xlDown).Address))
            End If
        Loop
    Next
    
End Sub
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try a different approach. You can use MINIFS to check if the B value is the smallest for the corresponding A value and if not, delete. This code does the deleting at the end, which is easier as it avoids missing rows and also the minimum being recalculated as you go.

```
Sub usunDuplikaty3()

Dim findRange As Range, cell As Range, rDel As Range

Set findRange = Range("A1", Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)) 'better to work up from the bottom

For Each cell In findRange
    If cell.Offset(, 1).Value <> WorksheetFunction.MinIfs(findRange.Offset(, 1), findRange, cell.Value) Then
    'alternative avoiding MINIFS
    'If cell.Offset(, 1).Value <> Evaluate("Min(If(" & findRange.Address & "=" & cell.Value & "," & findRange.Offset(, 1).Address & "))") Then
      If rDel Is Nothing Then
            Set rDel = cell
        Else
            Set rDel = Union(cell, rDel)
        End If
    End If
Next
    
If Not rDel Is Nothing Then rDel.EntireRow.Delete

End Sub
```

Comment: That's great and I appreciate it however in my office I only have access to Excel 2016 which does not have MinIfs function so I'll have to modify it a little bit to make it work. Thank you!

Comment: In that case you could use an array formula `=MIN(IF...` and `Evaluate`.

Comment: I actually tried something like `minIfRng.FormulaArray = "=MIN(IF(A1:" & findRange.End(xlDown).Address & "=" & cell.Address & ", IF(B1:" & findRange.Offset(, 1).End(xlDown).Address & "<> """", B1:" & findRange.Offset(, 1).End(xlDown).Address & ")))"` and then `cell.Offset(, 1).Value >= minIfRng.Value` in If statement but it still doesn't work as planned

Comment: I've added a line above which avoids MINIFS.

Comment: Thanks again, it works similar to my code but yours is obv better. But there is still one problem - if another cell with the same number and neighbour minimum value exist, it is not deleted.  So in the end there still is a duplicate pair. Any tip?

Comment: You could do an additional check using COUNTIF before deleting. Does it matter which gets deleted? Or once you deleted the first time do a removeduplicates?

Comment: Of course you are right, I could've thought about removeduplicates before asking another question. Thank you very much, I finally made it. :)